# The intersection of a sphere and plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

I'm working on the following problem from a practice midterm:

> Let C be the intersection of the sphere of radius 2 centered at the
>   origin and the plane y + z = 0.
>
> (a) Write parametric equations for C.
>
> (b) Choose your favorite point on C (any point will do) and write
>   parametric equations for the tangent line to C at that point.

For (a), I've gotten up to the point where I found the equation of the sphere ($x^2+y^2+z^2=4$). I also wrote $z$ as $z = -y$.

Now I'm not entirely sure how I'm supposed to parametrize this equation. My friend told me to 'say y = t' and to 'find z in terms of y' and 'x in terms of y.'

I interpreted this as plugging in z = -y into the equation for a sphere and solving accordingly. I got x = -2t+2, z = t, and y = t, though I'm not sure if I computed that correctly.

My question is this: is the reason why were are getting the parametric equation of C so that we can construct an equation we can take the derivative of so we can get the tangent line (what part b of the question is asking for, basically)? I'm confused as to why we're allowed to 'say y = t' when trying to compute the parametric equations - is there a generalized approach for finding the parametric equation of an intersection like C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of a sphere and a plane is a circle, and the projection of this circle in the $xy$ plane is the ellipse
$$
x^2+y^2+(-y)^2 = x^2+2y^2 = 4
$$
 This information we can use to find a suitable parametrization. Indeed, you can parametrize the ellipse as follows
$$
x= 2 \cos t\quad y = \sqrt{2} \sin t
$$
with $t\in [0,2\pi] $. And since you know that the curve belongs to the plane $z=-y$, you end up with 
\begin{cases}
x= 2 \cos t\\y = \sqrt{2} \sin t \qquad t\in [0,2\pi]\\ z=-\sqrt{2} \sin t
\end{cases}

Comment: If you could humor my follow up question, how did you arrive at $ x = 2 cos (t) $ and $y = √sin t$. Is this based on some property of ellipses/circles?

Comment: Yes, the ellipse $(x/a)^2 +(y/b)^2 =1$ has parametrization $x= a\cos t$, $y=b \sin t$. It is straightforward to check that these equations do indeed verify the equation of the ellipse.